# REST API with Azure Monitor

Tags: rest, azure-monitoring

We have Azure application (serverless functions) which number of REST API, used to communicate with Angular part of application as well as other systems in enterprise. I am looking the best way to monitor - "health check" those API, just a simple "ping" to see if service is up and running, so I was wondering if that could be done with Azure Monitor? Or for that matter is there other better way to check API.

I am going through [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview) but either I missed it or there is no explicit mention of how to do it - monitor application API. There is only section of how to use Azure monitor API. Any help on this, please? Best practices or nice tutorial would be great. Thanks.

EDIT: All API endpoints require authentication, including health check.

Comment: There is no authentication when ping the service? if yes, you can consider using application insights availability test for the ping operation.

Comment: @IvanYang Thanks. I updated question. All API endpoints require authentication.